# Custom Javascript / Scroll Spy Iteration is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I need a scroll spy function on a material design lite project, but the iteration is getting stuck at GroupB of the code below. I can't figure out why it's dieing. More detail and complete code here on this:

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/une6a39d/2/)

### html sidebar

```
<!-- Left Col -->

<nav class="bs-docs-sidebar" id="bs-docs-sidebar">
<ul>

    <li>
        <a href="#GroupA">Basics</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#GroupASub1" >Summery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#GroupB">Disorders</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#GroupBSub1">Disease Names</a></li>
            <li><a href="#GroupBSub2">Disease Information</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#GroupC">Genes</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#GroupCSub1">PGLFirst Genes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#GroupD">Testing</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#GroupDSub1">Benefits & Indication</a></li>
            <li><a href="#GroupDSub2">Description</a></li>
            <li><a href="#GroupDSub3">Mutation Detection Rate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#GroupDSub4">Specimen Requirements</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#GroupE">References</a>
    </li>

    <!-- Same for Group B & C -->
</ul>
</nav>
```

### Content Area

```
 <section id="GroupA" class="group">
   <h2>GroupA</h2>
   <div id="GroupASub1" class="subgroup">
   <h4>SubGroupA1</h4>
     <p>Yadda yadda</p>
     <p>yadda</p>
   </div>
 </section>

 <section id="GroupB" class="group">
   <h2>GroupB</h2>
   <div id="GroupBSub1" class="subgroup">
     <h4>SubGroup1</h4>
     <p>Yadda yadda</p>
     <p>yadda</p>
   </div>
   <div id="GroupBSub2" class="subgroup">
     <h4>SubGroup2</h4>
     <p>Yadda yadda</p>
     <p>yadda</p>
   </div>
 </section>

 <section id="GroupC" class="group">
   <h2>GroupC</h2>
   <div id="GroupCSub1" class="subgroup">
     <h4>SubGroup1</h4>
     <p>Yadda yadda</p>
     <p>yadda</p>
   </div>
 </section>

 <section id="GroupD" class="group">
   <h2>GroupD</h2>
   <div id="GroupDSub1" class="subgroup">
     <h4>SubGroup1</h4>
     <p>Yadda yadda</p>
     <p>yadda</p>
   </div>

   <div id="GroupDSub2" class="subgroup">
     <h4>SubGroup2</h4>
     <p>Yadda yadda</p>
     <p>yadda</p>
   </div>
 </section>

 <section id="GroupE" class="group">
  <h2>GroupE</h2>
  <div id="GroupESub1" class="subgroup">
    <h4>SubGroup1</h4>
    <p>Yadda yadda</p>
    <p>yadda</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

### JS

```
// This finds the scrollTop based on the page wrapper
$('.mdl-layout__content').on('scroll', function() {

  var windscroll = $('.mdl-layout__content').scrollTop(); // scrollTop variable - applied to content area.

  // Adds an active class to the left navigation based on scroll location of content
        $('.test-content section').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 83) {
                $('.bs-docs-sidebar li.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.bs-docs-sidebar li').eq(i).addClass('active');
            } else {
                $('.bs-docs-sidebar li.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.bs-docs-sidebar li:first').addClass('active');
            }
        });
}).scroll();
```